# Сложные прилагательные. Как определить: качественные или относительные?

Tags: сложные-слова, сложные-прилагательные

Скажите, пожалуйста, прилагательные: *мелкоклеточный* и *мелкодисперсный* — качественные или относительные?

Можно ли сказать "Эмульсионные продукты произведены с помощью ультразвука, позволяющего получать **очень** мелкодисперсные эмульсии?"

Answer (score 4):

Относительные!

> Относительные прилагательные характеризуют предмет через его отношение
>   к лицу, месту, времени, материалу, весу и т. д.: стальной, вчерашний и
>   др. Они имеют только полную форму.
>
> Не образуют степеней сравнения.
>
> Не имеют антонимов и не сочетаются с наречиями меры и степени.

**[источник](http://www.mylanguage.ru/materials/111/2957)**

---

Сказать *очень мелкодисперсные*, наверное, можно, как... *ну очень январский день*, подразумевая пик стужи. А вообще-то - не-а.

Comment: Замечу, что в технической и научной литературе выражения "более мелкодисперсные", "самые мелкодисперсные" и т.п. встречаются и выглядят в контексте вполне уместными.

Comment: Меня одолевают сомнения. А разве **крупнодисперсный** не является антонимом к **мелкодисперсному**?

Comment: Гриззличек, я не шарила в поисках антонимов или степеней. Ну это ж несомненно не качественные прилагательные. *Эта эмульсия мелкодисперснее той!"* )))

Comment: Я не спорю. Ответ поддержал, но мне было бы интересно разобраться глубже. (Понравился вопрос.)

Comment: Гиззлик, найди полный ответ: твои антипримеры хороши! )))

Comment: Нашёл удовлетворительный ответ. Не прошло и полгода :)

Answer (score 1):

Мне удалось найти ответы на свои вопросы (см. комментарии к ответу от @GalinaAvanesova). Я процитирую слова академика РАН Ю.Д. Апресяна из [этого интервью](https://www.bookvoed.ru/files/3515/54/70/5.pdf) (начало на стр. 12), которые показывают, что не существует какой-то жёсткой границы при переходе от относительных прилагательных к качественным.

> Возвращаясь к качественным и относительным прилагательным: в начале
>   шестидесятых годов в Институте русского языка Академии наук СССР было
>   проведено исследование свойств качественности — относительности на
>   большом массиве прилагательных и было обнаружено, что жесткой границы
>   между ними нет. Есть плавная шкала перехода от прототипических
>   качественных прилагательных (они обладают всеми шестью свойствами
>   качественности) к прототипическим относительным прилагательным (у них
>   нет ни одного такого свойства) через много промежуточных ступеней.
>   Есть пятерки / четверки / тройки и т. п. свойств качественности,
>   притом не обязательно одних и тех же у разных прилагательных.
>
> На самом деле картина еще сложнее. Вполне качественное прилагательное
>   может не обладать ни одним из его прототипических свойств, если оно
>   развивается в структуре многозначности исходно относительного
>   прилагательного. Возьмем прилагательные железный и стальной. В своих
>   главных значениях (железная стружка, стальная дверь) это, конечно,
>   относительные прилагательные. Но в значениях ‘крепкий’ (железные
>   мускулы, стальные мышцы) и ‘твердый’ (железная дисциплина, стальная
>   воля) они семантически становятся качественными прилагательными.
>   однако никаких формальных свойств качественных прилагательных (см.
>   выше) они не приобретают. В частности, у них нет кратких форм (едва ли
>   услышишь *Его мышцы железны <стальны>*), степеней сравнения (не говорят
>   *А у них дисциплина еще железнее* или *Его воля еще стальнее*) и т. п.,
>   при том, что их синонимы крепкий и твердый обладают всеми свойствами
>   качественных прилагательных.